# Prove that all cyclic groups are Abelian.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups

> Prove that all cyclic groups are Abelian.

For some group $G$, define a cyclic subgroup of $G$ as $\left \langle a \right \rangle = \{a^n : n \in \mathbb{Z}, a \in G\}$

Then it follows that $a^n,a^m \in \left \langle a \right \rangle$ is always true. We wish to show that $\left \langle a \right \rangle$ is abelian, or that 
$$a^na^m = a^ma^n$$
So...
$$a^na^m=a^{n+m}=a^{m+n}=a^ma^n$$
Hence, every cyclic group is Abelian since for all $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a^na^m=a^ma^n$.

> Is that really all we have to do? This proof seems way too easy but also right.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is all you need to do.

Comment: Note that $a^na^m=a^{n+m}$ is of course an important step. If you want to be formal about it, you can prove it via a couple of inductions, depending on your definition of exponentiation. But honestly IMO $(a\cdots_n a)(a\cdots_m a) = a\cdots_{n+m} a$ is a fine proof (with variations for $n$ or $m$ negative or $0$).